# How to access daynamically created components in a managed bean in jsf

Tags: jsf

I have created some button dynamically and i wanted to know which button is clicked on the managed bean all the buttons go to the same method and i what to determine which one is clicked.
This is how i created the button.

```
<ui:repeat var="o" value="#{postManagedBean.answer}" varStatus="status">
     <p:commandLink action="#{postManagedBean.add}" id="#{status.index}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Pass Index in action.

Comment: Note: the `id="#{status.index}"` is incorrect. This would only throw an exception that an empty `id` attribute is not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Add the index as a parameter for the action.

```
<ui:repeat var="o" value="#{postManagedBean.answer}" varStatus="status">
     <p:commandLink action="#{postManagedBean.add(status.index)}" id="#{status.index}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

This way you can access the index in the action method.